# mongodb $exists always returning 0

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a database collection (named fols) like so:

```
{'followers':
        {
           '123':1
           '123':2
           '123':3
         }
}
```

If I run the query (Using pymongo):

```
cursor = fols.find()
cursor.count()
>>3
```

Works fine. Now:

```
cursor = fols.find({'followers':{'123':1}})
cursor.count()
>>1
```

Again works fine. BUT if I try:

```
cursor = fols.find({'followers':{'123':{'$exists': True}}})
cursor.count()
>> 0
```

It returns 0 even though there are 3 records.

Comment: Can you clarify: Do you have a collection `followers` with three documents:  {'123': 1}, {'123': 2}, {'123': 3}  or do you have a collection `fols` that contains a single document with 3 subdocuments: {'followers': { '123': 1}, {'123': 2}, {'123': 3}} ?  Because they key '123' would be overwritten and only one copy remains.

Comment: I have a collection fols that contains a single document "followers" which contains the other values. And I can confirm that it is not being overwritten as if I do: fols.find(). It returns all my 3 documents.

Comment: If you have a single document in the fols collection, then fols.find() should only return a single document, not 3.  I tried this in the mongo shell:  db.fols.insert({'followers': {'123':1, '123':2, '123':3}})   and  with db.fols.find() get back { "_id" : ObjectId("505149486195484752df6214"), "followers" : { "123" : 3 } }.

Comment: Having an array with three times the say key *123" is *nonsense*. This will collapse to an array with ony key-value pair hiding two others.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When you're not matching a complete object you need to use [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to use an operator against an embedded object.  So in this case:

```
cursor = fols.find({'followers.123':{'$exists': True}})
```

Answer (score 5):

Try the dot syntax:

```
cursor = fols.find({'followers.123': {'$exists': True}})
```

But also see my comment above. You can't have the same key more than once in a (sub-)document.