# how to declare query to fetch data from mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

```
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def _connect_mongo(host, port, db):
    """ A util for making a connection to mongo 

    if username and password:
        mongo_uri = 'mongodb://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s' % (username, password, host, port, db)
        conn = MongoClient(mongo_uri)
    else:
    """    
    conn = MongoClient(host, port)


    return conn[db]


def read_mongo(db, collection, host, port, query):
    """ Read from Mongo and Store into DataFrame """

    # Connect to MongoDB
    db = _connect_mongo(host=host, port=port, db=db)

    # Make a query to the specific DB and Collection
    cursor = db[collection].find(query)

    # Expand the cursor and construct the DataFrame
    df =  pd.DataFrame(list(cursor))

    '''
     Delete the _id
    if no_id:
        del df['_id']
    '''
    return df    


#initialization
db = 'twittersmall'
collection='twitterdata'
query='{lang:{$exists: true}}'
host='localhost'
port=27017

var = read_mongo(db, collection, host, port, query)
print var

tweets_by_lang = var['lang'].value_counts()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=15)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=10)
ax.set_xlabel('Languages', fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Number of tweets' , fontsize=15)
ax.set_title('Top 5 languages', fontsize=15, fontweight='bold')
tweets_by_lang[:5].plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', color='red')
```

In this code, I was trying to fetch those data from mongodb where language  field exists(might be null). So in the attribute, `query` I assigned a filter that will be used in the fetching operation. But the problem is, when I initialize `query='{lang:{$exists: true}}'`, `query`  is of string datatype and query must be a dictionary. When I declare `query={lang:{$exists: true}}` , it says -> `syntax error`. Obviously because so far as I know declaration of dictionary is `{'key':'value'}` . And when I declare like this `query={'lang':'{$exists: true}'}` it doesn't work  because of `keyError` as there's filed in the database called `lang`.

So, how to declare this query and pass it in the method?

ps: when I use `query={lang:{$exists: true}}` in `Webstorm` terminal, it works, but I am currently working on `jupyter notebook` that integrates `ipython`, so that I can create graph, charts using the data from mongodb. I also  used `pandas` for `dataframe`.

Comment: Did you try query as query={'lang':{'$exists':True}} ???

Comment: The documentation in MongoDB says, the syntax is {field : {$exists: <bool>} }

Comment: Yes but you should send that command over python driver. For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398625/mongodb-exists-always-returning-0 here you can see the appropriate code format.

Comment: But where should I use the dot operator. In the db, it's like
lang:eng;  lng:esp etc.